# Identify android device after reset

Tags: android, security

I want to identify an android device even after a total factory reset.

I know that I can use the android-device-id, but it changes if the user resets the device.

As the Mac address is not available and IMEI not on very device, like tablets without sim, the android-id changes on reset, is there a possible way to be at least 90% sure that the device is the same after a reset?